# Is there a way to import Android Studio Gradle Files into Xamarin (Visual Studio)?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have an Xamarin with Visual Studio 2015 and I wondered if you could load Android Studio Gradle files into Xamarin?

Comment: No answer yet? ... Oh yeah, it's xamarin. :(